# How to set different constraints or test cases in Specman e language

Tags: specman

I want to use different constraints for din1 and din2. For example, it will execute `din1<10` and `din2<1000` first 10 times and then execute `din1<5` and `din2<10` for 10 times.
How can I do this?

[image: my code]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#285557). Why is this tagged `verilog` ?

Answer (score 0):

this is one simple way to constrain list of structs:

```
keep insts.size() == 20;

keep for each in insts {
    index < 10 =>  (it.din1 < 10 and it.din2 < 1000);
    index >= 10 => (it.din1 < 5 and it.din2 < 10);
};
```